# Cannot connect to Access2016 file stored at same location from an Excel2016 userform

Tags: excel, vba

I am using front end as Excel2016 and back end is Access2016.
This is a shared file to be used by multiple users for data entry, so after each function I release the connection object.

I fetch the table data at `Workbook_Open()` event and it works absolutely fine.
I have a userform for data entry. I have used the same code, and surprisingly this time `ActiveWorkbook.Path` works fine for me, but does not return same path for other users.

I have also tried defining public variable in General Declaration area of my Userform (`Public strPath As String`), and in `Workbook_Open()` setting the value of variable ( Set strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path ) but that won't work either.

I am attaching my current code for reference. open_connection() is called via button click in userform.

**Workbook_Open()**

```
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strDBName = "Test Excel Access.accdb"
strDB = strPath & "\" & strDBName

ConnDB.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

strTable = "Table01"

adoRecSet.Open Source:=strTable, ActiveConnection:=ConnDB, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic

' perform init operations

adoRecSet.Close
Set adoRecSet = Nothing
ConnDB.Close
Set ConnDB = Nothing

Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ThisWorkbook.Save
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
```

**open_connection()**

```
strPath = ActiveWorkbook.Path
strDBName = "Test Excel Access.accdb"
strDB = strPath & "\" & strDBName

ConnDB.Open ConnectionString:="Provider = Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; data source=" & strDB

strTable = "Table01"

adoRecSet.Open Source:=strTable, ActiveConnection:=ConnDB, CursorType:=adOpenDynamic, LockType:=adLockOptimistic
```

Is there a way I can use value of strPath from Workbook_Open() in my userform? Or how can I get same path when I use the ActiveWorkbook.Path function in UserForm.

Comment: Have you tried to you use `ThisWorkbook.Path`?

Comment: @FunThomas  Yes, I started with `ThisWorkbook.Path` but it didn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this issue by storing the path of my workbook to a cell in `Workbook_Open()` and using the cell value as path later in userform.